# Import a 3D model with lightmap from 3DS Max into a three.js app

Tags: three.js, 3dsmax

I'm struggling to find the most suitable workflow for 3DS Max and THREE.JS.

I've been using the Max exporter:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/max/ThreeJSExporter.ms

but it seems it's unable to export more than one UV set (channel).

I can't use OBJ format because it doesn't support multiple UV channels at all.

I suppose I could save a file to .fbx, open it in blender and use the blender exporter:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender

which seems to support multiple UV channels, but this is quite a long path and I'm not sure the graphic team would follow it through.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Perhaps you can file an enhancement request for the Max exporter on the three.js github site. Or fix it yourself and submit a pull request. :-)

Comment: Yup, meanwhile I found a fbx to threejs converter: http://verold.com/blog/2012/11/27/designing-the-fbx-converter-for-threejs#.U7Vvx_l_t8F but it doesn't work with --flatten-scene option. I'm not sure if I have the skills to fix this kind of stuff, but it looks like I've got no choice.

Comment: Actually it works! I think this would be the best workflow in my case. Thank you for your interest, WestLangley.